# SlidingMenu Library with ActionBarSherlock error on ResposiveUIActivity

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu

I have an error at this line at the beginning of the file ResponsiveUIActivity.java :

public class ResponsiveUIActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

How can I do to correct this error in the package :

*com.slidingmenu.example.fragments*

?

--

Error:

The hierarchy of the type ResponsiveUIActivity is inconsistent

I use GoogleAPI 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your activity extend `SlidingFragmentActivity`, construct your menu programmatically like this:

```
        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
```